# performance issue for loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix, distance

I have two matrices A and B. Both contain a list of names.The question is based on similarity measure.I find the smallest distance of an element of A from B(the whole matrix).If the hamming distance is greater than 3 , then the data is to be added in matrix B , otherwise not.  so let me give you an example

```
 A<-c("cvombiflam","combiflam")
 A<-as.matrix(A)

 B<-c("windfall","computer","baseball")
 B<-as.matrix(B)
```

Now A1 will search B and find the closest member of B with respect to hamming distance.The closest is B2. It will find the distance with B[2]. Since the closest distance is greater than 3, therefore cvomiflam will be added to B. Now B will be

```
 B<-c("windfall",
      "computer",
      "baseball",
      "cvombiflam")
```

Now second element of A("combiflam") will search B. The closest is fourth element of B (cvombiflam )with distance as 1. Therefore combiflam will not be added in B. I want to have the final B list updated

the code I have written is:

```
 for(i in 1:length(A))
 {    
      d<-min(stringdistmatrix(A[i],B)
      if(d>3)
      {            
           B<-rbind(B,A[i])
      }
 }
```

Now I have A matrix of around 140,000 and B of 200,000. The code is working fine but it is taking ages to run. Please tell me a faster way to do it.

Comment: Did you accidentally double-post this? Here's the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940635/improving-performance-for-loop-r

Comment: yes, but I just now flagged the other post for it to be deleted

Comment: `strindist` can leverage multiple cores (if available).

Comment: Hi Ricardo, could you please clarify

Comment: Please always make sure to mention any used packages, here `stringdist`. Also, you mention the hamming distance, but it appears the default distance used in that `stringdistmatrix` function is `osa`: `Optimal string aligment, (restricted Damerau-Levenshtein distance).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of growing `B` over and over, which is costly and may end up fragmenting your memory space, you could just store and update a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` indicating if an element of `A` should be added to `B` or not. Then, only at the end, append these selected elements to `B`.

Another thing to note is you are using matrices everywhere when you only need vectors. I fixed that for you.

```
A <- as.vector(A)
B <- as.vector(B)

add.A <- rep(FALSE, length(A))

for(i in 1:length(A)) {
  if (i %% 1000L == 0L) cat(sprintf("%.2f percent completed", 100 * i / length(A)))
  d.B <- stringdist(A[i], B)
  d.A <- stringdist(A[i], A[add.A])
  d <- min(c(d.B, d.A))
  if (d > 3) {            
    add.A[i] <- TRUE
  }
}

B <- c(B, A[add.A])
```

That thing being addressed, your problem dimensions are still huge. A lot of distances (at least  `length(A) * length(B)`) are to be computed and this will take a lot of time. I added a `cat` in the loop to give you an idea of how long it will take as it runs. Please give it a try and comment as to how slow or fast it is.

Also, in case `A` and `B` have items in common, you could initially reduce your problem dimensions by doing:

```
A <- unique(A)
B <- unique(B)
A <- setdiff(A, B)
```

Comment: I need to grow B iteratively and then check with A

Comment: @user2678307. If you read my code carefully, at every step, the current element in `A` is compared with all elements in `B` plus all elements selected from `A` so far. In other words, I am exactly reproducing your algorithm, except in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you grow the object `B` iteratively (`B = rbind(B, A[i]`). This is very slow as the memory size requirements constantly grow for `B`. Constantly extending `B` memory-wise takes very long, causing your loop to become very slow. You could do a few things to solve this:

- Preallocate `B` to the correct size before the loop and fill it in the loop.
- Use an `apply` style loop, and `rbind` at the very end:

  ```
  list_of_results = lapply(A, stringdistmatrix, b = B)
  big_data_frame = do.call('rbind', list_of_results)
  ```

Other options to speed up calculations:

- Use multiple cores, see `ncores` argument to `stringdistmatrix`.
- Experiment with different distance measures (`method` argument) to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Look at his problem size, computing all distances in one shot will blow up the memory usage...